# I have a function in script but I can't find who is calling it

Tags: unix, tcl

I have a function in script but I can't find who is calling it.
I tried using grep but I can't find it. Maybe it is in different path.
How can I get it from tcl ?
For example, in csh there is an option to use with "echo $0"

I use with linux.

Comment: What do you mean by 'who is calling it'? The user running the script?

Comment: No. the main script run by user. I talk about a big code. The files can be in different directories. @Shawn

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`info frame -1`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/info.htm#M15):

```
proc foo {} {
    bar
}

proc bar {} {
   puts [info frame -1]
}

foo
# => type proc line 1 cmd bar proc ::foo level 1
```

So you could read that using `dict` like `dict get [foo] proc` and you'll get `::foo`, meaning the proc which called bar is foo (in the global namespace).

---

EDIT: Something you may try to get all the commands executed along the way:

```
proc a {} {b}
proc b {} {c}
proc c {} {
    for {set i 1} {$i < [info level]} {incr i} {
        puts [info frame -$i]
    }
}

a
# => type proc line 1 cmd c proc ::b level 1
#    type proc line 1 cmd b proc ::a level 2
```

Comment: Do you know how I can get the path link of called function ? @Jerry

Comment: @Alex You mean like the whole sequence of commands that have been called to reach the proc you are looking at? You could use a loop and going from `info frame -1` to `info frame -N`. I'll add it to my answer in a bit

Comment: It doesn't help. I want to get path. I get only the func name. @Jerry

Comment: @Alex if there are multiple files involved, there's a new component returned by info frame, with the key `file`. It looks like this on my machine `type source line 7 file C:/Users/user/script2.tcl cmd foo::c proc ::b level 1` and `type source line 4 file C:/Users/user/script.tcl cmd b proc ::a level 2` where in one file I simply sourced and the other I used package require.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` to walk thru all the files:

```
grep -l -R name_of_the_finction /
```

this will print the filename when this function is called or defined.

Of course there is another way, you activate `audit` daemon, set to be monitored read operations for this particular file (where the function is defined) and wait. Time to time check the audit logs and you will see process, user, file which open the file in question for read.

If you want to use audit you can check in those articles [1](http://unixswing.blogspot.com/2018/12/audit-something-you-have-something-you.html), [2](http://unixswing.blogspot.com/2018/12/audit-something-you-have-something-you_10.html) in my personal blog.

Comment: I will get the answer after a few days. There are a very many files. @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @Alex, you can ask the author of the script(s), check some internal documentation, wait....

Comment: I can't ask the author. It's my problem. I have only the source code. @Romeo Ninov

Comment: audit @Romeo Ninov

Comment: @Alex, check edited answer with links to my personal blog